# Redirect the user to profile after registeration

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a Login/Registeration System, Everything is done, password is encrypted, Using `PDO` to prevent SQL Injections. etc...

The only problem that I have is, Just like Facebook, I want to immediately redirect the user after the success registration to their profile, So when they click `submit` on the **registration** form, I want to redirect them to their profile, So It should display something like this, `You're logged in as Akar`, I set the `$_SESSION['logged_in']` to `1`. But it doesn't display the name. So instead of `You're logged in as Akar`, It displays `You're logged in as`, blank, It doesn't display my name.

Here is my code:

```
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (first_name, last_name, email, username, password, gender, birthday)
    VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :username, :password, :gender, :birthday)";
    $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $first_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $last_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam(':birthday', $birthday);
    $user_register = $stmt->execute();

    if ($user_register) {
         $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
        //$this->messages[] = "Your account has been succesfully registered, Login above!";
```

And the `$row` variable is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
$stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

I fixed it, By doing this:

```
            if ($user_register) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
            $stmt = $this->db_connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
```

Thanks...

Comment: You don't define `$row` anywhere? And also, we're not going to fix your problem, we're going to help you fix it yourself. At least that's what should happen..

Comment: I defined above. Not in current code.

Comment: Show it in the question perhaps.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. You say you define `$row` above the code you're having trouble with. How do you fetch information about the user before he has registered? Also consider enabling `error_reporting()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the user to another page(as i understand thats what you want to do)

Execute this code:

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/account_page.php' );
```

Comment: I want to redirect them, But with the `$_SESSION` variables. So I can display the name.

Comment: If its on the same host the session is still saved on the users cache, and you could just define it again with: $username =   $_SESSION['username']

Answer (score 0):

Wait, what is $row equal to? ;)  `http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php`
Do $row = $stm->fetch();
Your problem should be solved I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said:

> when they click submit on the registration form, I want to redirect them to their profile

How about use

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

instead ? sorry I'm not allowed to add comment